# Connecting remotely to postgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, remote-access, pgadmin

I'm trying to connect remotely on pgAdmin to a database hosted on a Windows 10 PC on another network from my personal PC.

Steps taken:

- Changed `listen_addresses = 'localhost'` to `listen_addresses = '*'` in postgresql.conf file.
- Added line `host all all 0.0.0.0/0` to pg_hba.conf file.
- Restarted postgresql service.
- Opened port in firewall for port 5432

Tried to connect to database via pgAdmin on my PC by entering:

- Host name: IPv4 address of machine database is hosted on.
- Port:5432, Database: postgres, user: postgres, password: password

I can't see any error except a connection timed out error every time, but I don't know why. I've increased the connection timeout duration but still no connection. PostgreSQL service is running and I can connect to the database via pgAdmin just fine on the hosting PC.

Can anyone let me know if I'm skipping a step or anything else I need to add to the config files?
Thanks

Comment: Can you connect to the database-machine from a terminal ? (ssh, putty,...)

Comment: No, it says connection refused, but I'm also not sure I've entered everything correctly. I am however able to connect to psql via the command prompt.

Comment: Sounds like a firewall.  Either on the server machine, or between you and the server.

Comment: Firewalls are turned off on both PC's but still unable to connect